# Canvas rendering resolution - how to use a canvas in a flex layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I'm using a flex environment to automatically scale a container with fixed sides and header (header loaded using jquery on document ready).

```
--------------
|  header    |
--------------
|  |canvas|  |
|  |      |  |
--------------
```

There are 2 flex environments, one from the top to bottom (column) and one from left to right (row).

This seems to work normally when not taking the canvas into account.
As the canvas is scaled when the page loads and the flex is applied, its size changes while leaving the context's "render" width/height the same. This leads to the image being rendered at a small resolution and getting stretched.

To solve this issue, before rendering I run this function each time:

```
Map._resizeCanvas = function (canvas) {
    let displayWidth = canvas.clientWidth;
    let displayHeight = canvas.clientHeight;

    if(displayWidth !== canvas.width || displayHeight !== canvas.height) {
        canvas.width = displayWidth;
        canvas.height = displayHeight;
    }
};
```

This most of the time works but leads to an image that is strechted by a few pixels (along X).
Sometimes it causes the header to disappear or increase the page height therefore adding a scroll bar.

How can I use a canvas inside of a flex environment? Is there something I need to take into account when I set the canvas width? (like margins, paddings, I already set the display style to block, inline broke the entire paage)

Is there a way to set the context's rendering resolution without changing the layout and affecting the page?

HTML:

```
<body>

<div id="header-navigation"></div> <!-- set by jquery on document ready -->

<div id="page-container">
    <div class="container" id="container1">
        abc
        <div style="height: 50pt;"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="container" id="container2">
        <canvas id="canvas1" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block"></canvas>
    </div>

    <div class="container" id="container3">
        abc
        <div style="height: 50pt;"></div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
}

p {
    margin: 0;
}

#header-navigation {
    overflow: hidden; /* FIXME, in the flex environment, this also overflows in width */
    flex: 0 1 auto;
}

#page-container {
    margin: 5pt;
    flex: 1 1 auto; /* part of the column flex layout */

    display: flex; /* contains the row flex */
    flex-flow: row;
}

.container {
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 5pt;
    margin-right: 5pt;
}

#container1 {
    background: lightgray;
    flex: 0 1 15%;
}

#container2 {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

#container3 {
    background: lightgray;
    flex: 0 1 15%;
}

#canvas1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My main issue was the shrink value in the flex parameter. It allowed the top bar to vanish on decreasing the page size.

I didn't find a way to solve the issue of the canvas rendering resolution not exactly matching it's actual size, so lines sometimes still blur. Setting the canvas' shrink option to 0 mostly solves this, but the rest of the UI breaks then. I suspect it is caused by the Element actually having a non integer width which isn't represented by the clientWidth/offsetWidth parameters.